# Anyway to login to google using volley or okhttp?

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp, google-signin

I am trying to access into a website which is login by google account. But I do not know is it possible to login to google using okhttp or volley (or something else)? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need google api's OAuth to login. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

Comment: But I am not the owner of this web, I just want to login to it and get some data

Comment: @PhạmSỹHưng you can't